# Read and write excel

Tags: php, symfony

hello I have this method to make a file upload excel I want to read the contents of this file and change who can help me

```
public function chargement_ticket_ouvertAction (){
         $dossier = 'C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\src\Admin\BlogBundle\Resources\views\GestionAlerte\upload';

           $post=$_FILES['avatar'];
           $fichier = basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
           $file = $_FILES['avatar']. $dossier;

           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier)) //Si la fonction renvoie TRUE, c'est que ça a fonctionné...
        {   

              return new response ('Upload effectué avec succès !'.$file);

          }


          else //Sinon (la fonction renvoie FALSE).
         {
                    return new response('Echec de l\'upload !');

         }


    }
```

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you but i use symfony :( how to implemente phpexcel with symfony?

Comment: The same way you would without symfony. PHPExcel is just some PHP files that you can `include()`. [Here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) is a simple example.

Comment: thank you where I put the package PHPExcel?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Symfony 2.1 with composer it's as easy as including the phpexcel package.

Add it to composer.json

```
"require": {
  "phpexcel/phpexcel": "1.*@stable"
}
```

Then update/install this package

```
composer update phpexcel/phpexcel
```

Then you can use it like so

```
$excel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('/path/to/excel.file');
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
```

Comment: did you run composer update? i've added that step to the answer

Comment: It's the standard install procedure for adding packages with composer. In your projects composer.json file you should have a "require" section listing your projects dependencies; add the phpexcel line there. Which version of Symfony are you using and how did you install it? Is it from the standard edition?

Comment: I have Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.17

Comment: ah, 2.0 didn't use composer, and especially not the version with pre-packaged vendors. You'll have to dig around the phpexcel site and download the package, put it somewhere in your vendor directory, and figure out how to autoload it in app/autoload.php. I'm not sure exactly what that would look like, unfortunately.